# I can't get the content of a web page without html codes in C#

Tags: c#, html, webclient, windows-forms-designer

I want to get the text of a web page in **windows form application**. I am using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString(link);
```

However, it gave me **html codes of the web page**. 
Here is the question:

Can I get the specific part of a website? For example a part that has a class name **"ask-page new-topbar"**. I want to get every part that has class name **"ask-page new-topbar"**.

Comment: You can manually do that or load it into an [HtmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) once you have retrieved it with the method above. You have to retrieve it first though, there is nothing that will only retrieve a part of the html document.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't get only parts of a website, when you send a request to a url.

What you can do is use the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) and let it dig through the Html code to give you the contents of the requested node.